# Angular 9 testing error: Zone is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found

Tags: angular-cli, karma-jasmine, angular-test, zone.js

As above, trying to test but getting the error

```
Zone is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found
```

I also get
     An error was thrown in afterAll
      Uncaught TypeError: require.context is not a function
      TypeError: require.context is not a function
          at Object.global.wrappers./Users/edwardthompson/e4repo/evidentia/projects/date-calculator/src/test.ts.zone.js/dist/zone (src/test.ts:3:28)

I have the generated test.ts defined, and angular.json seems properly configured
I can remove the dependency on async by inlining the template, but that leaves the second error, which seems to imply that test.ts is not in the loop?

Pulling my hair out.  troubleshooting suggestions? can you see something I can't?

test.ts:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: {
    context(
        path: string,
        deep?: boolean,
        filter?: RegExp
    ): {
        keys(): string[];
        <T>(id: string): T;
    };
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

angular.json:

```
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
  "options": {
    "main": "projects/date-calculator/src/test.ts",
    "tsConfig": "projects/date-calculator/tsconfig.spec.json",
    "karmaConfig": "projects/date-calculator/karma.conf.js",
    "preserveSymlinks": true
  }
},
```

the test itself is pretty vanilla:

```
describe('DateCalculatorComponent', () => {
    let component: DateCalculatorComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DateCalculatorComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                MatCardModule,
                MatToolbarModule,
                MatFormFieldModule,
                FormsModule,
                MatProgressSpinnerModule,
                MatIconModule,
                MatInputModule,
                MatButtonModule,
                CommonModule,
                ClipboardModule,
                EvDirectivesModule
            ],
            declarations: [DateCalculatorComponent],
            providers: [DateCalculatorService]
        }).compileComponents()
            .then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DateCalculatorComponent);
                component = fixture.componentInstance;
            });
    }));

    fit(`Given an Angular app is running
         Then the component should be defined`, (() => {
        return expect(component).to.not.be.undefined;
    }));
});
```

Comment: please provide a reproduce repo.